# Generate switch cases for each type in a tuple/parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement, c++17

I am trying to figure out how to use template "magic" to automatically generate a switch statement for each type in a tuple.  Here is my example code:

```
#include <string>

enum class AttributeID
{
    ATTRIBUTE1,
    ATTRIBUTE2,
    ATTRIBUTE3
};

struct ATTRIBUTE1
{
    static constexpr auto kID = AttributeID::ATTRIBUTE1;
    using Value = unsigned int;
    
    Value v;
};

struct ATTRIBUTE2
{
    static constexpr auto kID = AttributeID::ATTRIBUTE2;
    using Value = char;
    
    Value v;
};

struct ATTRIBUTE3
{
    static constexpr auto kID = AttributeID::ATTRIBUTE3;
    using Value = std::string;
    
    Value v;
};

class Attributes
{
public:
    using ID = AttributeID;
    
    template <typename T>
    auto& get()
    {
        return std::get<T>(impl_).v;
    }
    
private:
    std::tuple<ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2, ATTRIBUTE3> impl_;
};

template <typename Attribute>
void foodleAttribute(Attribute& attr, unsigned int data)
{
    //...
    //This template will be specialized based upon the type of Attribute
}

void fiddleAttribute(Attributes& attrs, Attributes::ID id, unsigned int data)
{
    switch(id)
    {
    case ATTRIBUTE1::kID:
        foodleAttribute(attrs.get<ATTRIBUTE1>(), data);
        break;
    case ATTRIBUTE2::kID:
        foodleAttribute(attrs.get<ATTRIBUTE2>(), data);
        break;
    case ATTRIBUTE3::kID:
        foodleAttribute(attrs.get<ATTRIBUTE3>(), data);
        break;
    }
}
```

I would like to rewrite the `fiddleAttribute` function as such

```
template <typename Attributes>
void fiddleAttribute(Attributes& attrs, typename Attributes::ID id, unsigned int data)
{
    //Generate a switch case (or equivalent) for each type (its kID constant) in the Attributes tuple
}
```

So that it generates something equivalent to the explicit switch statement I wrote (switch on the `id`, call the templated `foodleAttribute` function).

Comment: You would need reflection for something like this.  One option if you need to do this in many places is to build a map that maps the enum value to a functor that returns the correct type and then you can have a syntax like `foodleAttribute(accessor_func_map[id](attrs), data)`

Comment: Sounds a lot like `std::visit`, but on tuple instead of variant. Perhaps you could draw inspiration from that implementation.

Comment: Assuming your enum values are continuous, it is certainly doable with `std::index_sequence`, but right now your code has compile errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is to use a `std::index_sequence` with a fold expression. (Credits to @TedLyngmo for actually including `kID` in the solution and relaxing the restriction that the `id`s should be continuous)

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
void fiddleAttributeImpl(Attributes& attrs, Attributes::ID id, unsigned int data, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    void(((id == std::tuple_element_t<Is, Types>::kID
            && (foodleAttribute(attrs.get<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Types>>(), data), false)) || ...));
}

void fiddleAttribute(Attributes& attrs, Attributes::ID id, unsigned int data)
{
    fiddleAttributeImpl(attrs, id, data, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Types>>{});
}
```

The expression to be folded is

```
id == std::tuple_element_t<Is, Types>::kID 
            && (foodleAttribute(attrs.get<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Types>>(), data), true)
```

The part after `&&` is only executed if the runtime `id` equals the corresponding `kID`. The comma operator makes the subexpression evaluate to true and short circuits to avoid further comparsion. We use `std::tuple_element_t` to obtain the `Is`th type from the type list.

See Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/xaYd8a8r6

---

Alternatively, an approach that is more similar in nature to a switch statement is to build an array of function pointers from lambdas, which is then indexed at run time. In the following implementation the `id`s are assumed to be continuous and start from `0`. I am not entirely sure whether this restriction can be lifted without building an additional map.

Here we use the unary plus operator trick to convert the non-capturing lambdas to raw function pointers, which is more efficient than using e.g. `std::function`s. We also make use of CTAD so that we don't need to manually specify the template arguments for `std::array`.

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
void fiddleAttributeImpl(Attributes& attrs, Attributes::ID id, unsigned int data, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    static constexpr std::array
    jumpTable{
        +[](Attributes& attrs, unsigned int data){foodleAttribute(attrs.get<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Types>>(), data);}
        ...
    };
    
    jumpTable[static_cast<int>(id)](attrs, data);
}
```

See compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/Wc6TnrEnv

Answer (score 0):

A solution (perhaps not the nicest) that I came up with is to use macros to generate boilerplate code and the switch statement.  The following code makes used of the map macro from https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro

```
#define TW_ATTRIBUTES(...)\
    namespace detail\
    {\
    enum class ID : uint8_t\
    {\
        MAP_LIST(XTW_ATTRIBUTES_ENUM, __VA_ARGS__)\
    };\
    }\
    MAP(XTW_ATTRIBUTES_STRUCT,__VA_ARGS__)\
    class Attributes\
    {\
    public:\
        using ID = detail::ID;\
        Attributes() :\
            impl_{MAP_LIST(XTW_ATTRIBUTES_INIT_LIST,__VA_ARGS__)}\
        {\
        }\
        template <typename T>\
        auto get() const\
        {\
            return std::get<T>(impl_).v;\
        }\
        template <typename T, typename U>\
        void set(U&& v)\
        {\
            std::get<T>(impl_).v = std::forward<U>(v);\
        }\
        template <typename T>\
        auto& get()\
        {\
            return std::get<T>(impl_).v;\
        }\
    private:\
        std::tuple<MAP_LIST(XTW_ATTRIBUTES_TYPES, __VA_ARGS__)> impl_;\
    };\
    template <template<typename> typename Setter, typename Value>\
    bool setAttribute(Attributes& attributes, Attributes::ID id, Value v)\
    {\
        switch (id)\
        {\
        MAP(XTW_ATTRIBUTES_CASE,__VA_ARGS__);\
        }\
        return false;\
    }\
    
#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_ENUM(x_)\
    XTW_ATTRIBUTES_ENUMX x_

#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_ENUMX(id_, name_, type_, default_)\
    name_ = id_

#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_TYPES(x_)\
    XTW_ATTRIBUTES_TYPESX x_

#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_TYPESX(id_, name_, type_, default_)\
    name_

#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_STRUCT(x_)\
    XTW_ATTRIBUTES_STRUCTX x_

#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_STRUCTX(id_, name_, type_, default_)\
    struct name_\
    {\
        static constexpr auto kID = detail::ID::name_;\
        using Value = type_;\
        using value_type = Value;\
        Value v;\
    };
    
#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_INIT_LIST(x_)\
    XTW_ATTRIBUTES_INIT_LISTX x_

#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_INIT_LISTX(id_, name_, type_, default_)\
    {default_}
    
#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_CASE(x_)\
    XTW_ATTRIBUTES_CASEX x_

#define XTW_ATTRIBUTES_CASEX(id_, name_, type_, default_)\
    case name_::kID:\
        return Setter<name_::Value>::set(attributes.get<name_>(), v);
```

Which may be used as such:

```
namespace test
{
TW_ATTRIBUTES(
    (0x00, ATTRIBUTE1, unsigned int, 10),
    (0x01, ATTRIBUTE2, int32_t, -35)
);
}
```

Then, because the macro generates a templated `setAttribute` function, you can use if on any template class type which exposes a `set` method with the appropriate signature.

```
namespace foo
{

using Value = std::span<const std::byte>;

template <typename T, typename Enabled = void>
struct FooSetter;

template <typename T>
struct FooSetter<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
{
    static bool set(T& a, Value bytes)
    {
        std::span<std::byte> aBytes(reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&a), sizeof(T));
        
        //Just copy byte-for-byte
        auto i = bytes.begin();
        auto j = aBytes.begin();
        const auto iEnd = bytes.end();
        const auto jEnd = aBytes.end();

        while ((i != iEnd) && (j != jEnd))
        {
            *j++ = *i++;
        }

        while (j != jEnd)
        {
            *j++ = 0_b;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
};

} //namespace foo

int main()
{
    test::Attributes attributes;
    
    const std::byte kAttr1[] = {0x40_b, 0x1F_b, 0x00_b, 0x00_b};
    test::setAttribute<foo::FooSetter, foo::Value>(attributes, test::ATTRIBUTE1::kID, {kAttr1, sizeof(kAttr1)});

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not saying that it's pretty, but, in my tests, it does the job well.

Comment: `std::span` requires C++20 and there's really no need for the macro magic when a simpler solution is what Weijun Zhou presented, especially in the first version which can be made to work with `enum`s "out of order" as I described in a comment under that answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that std:;span is only available past C++20.  It's not super important to the meat of my "solution" though.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps the C++17 restriction should be lifted in the question? Weijun Zhou's solution can be made even more compact in C++20.